# Procedural wear and tear on a large number of identical objects

Tags: texturing, procedural

How would one go about generating procedural wear and tear on a large number of otherwise identical objects?
I'd like to make the wear different for each object.

Comment: Use generated texture coordinates for textures to add wear etc

Comment: For linked data objects: *Object info* node->Random output

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help.